# Certain POST requests are not processed by PHP on IIS

Tags: php, post, iis, upload, fastcgi

I'm sending POST requests to web service (IIS 10 with PHP 7 via FastCGI). 
Majority of requests are successfully processed, but there are few requests (about 1 in a 100) that are not processed. Problem is, that it seems, that the request fails on IIS, as I'm logging every request when the php web service is called, and I get no log message from these requests.

This is my php.ini configuration:

```
upload_max_filesize = 30M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 180
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 30M
```

This is my web.config configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="600000000" maxQueryString="600000000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
            <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is row from IIS log in inetpub/logs for failed request:

```
2019-01-18 14:08:30 ::1 POST /site/index - 8180 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/40.0.2214.115+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 64 2406
```

**sc-win32-status** is **64**, which should be "`ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`".

Here are some additional informations:

- Size of the requests are about 10 MB, same as successful requests.
- I somehow managed to get a log message in PHP few hours ago and the
  request was basically missing POST data (but I know the request was
  ok when it is sent)
- There is no redirection, I'm calling full address. Request is from
  the same server where the web service is.

Comment: This question is too vague. Where does the POST come from? Is it always from the same source when it fails? You say: _"but I know the request was ok"_, how did you determine that?

Comment: Btw, doesn't `500` in the log (after the user agent) indicate a HTTP 500 error? (I'm not an expert on IIS-logs, but I can't see any other value that would be a status code). Then you need to check if you have any other log files that logs PHP errors. Also make sure that you have PHP's error reporting turned on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have an app which calls the web service, so the source is 
 always same. I know that the requests are valid when sent because they are logged when an error occurs. 
Yes it is HTTP 500 error. I tried to set php logfile in php.ini with 'error_log' but no log has been created so far.

Comment: It's the web server that logs the errors, not PHP itself. Check [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7) out. Also check the comments under the accepted answer since it shows how some solved the logging issue.

Comment: Use utilities like FRT to collect more info on the actual error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis then you can dig further to see what's up.

Comment: To anyone else arriving here as desperate as I did: In my case it was that HTTP/2 was enabled, somehow this didn't go well with my old PHP 5.6 application and caused exactly the behavior that was described. Try disabling HTTP/2 on your IIS PHP Site.